# mysql #1054 - Unknown column in 'where clause' when update, but can be selected

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

I'm quite confused with this problem.

I have a table of `purchase_list` that about like this:

```
purchase_code  item  unit  order_amount  recived_amount  price
TRX-000001        1     1             0              85  14200
```

Then i try to update that record with this query:

```
UPDATE `purchase_list` 
SET `order_amount`='85'
WHERE `purchase_code`='TRX-000001' AND `item`='1' AND `unit`='1'
```

And end up with error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'unit' in 'where clause'
```

But when i do `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT `order_amount`
FROM `purchase_list` 
WHERE `purchase_code`='TRX-000001' AND `item`='1' AND `unit`='1'
```

it does show result:

```
order_amount
           0
```

And when I click phpmyadmin's `Simulate query` button, it does says:

```
Matched rows: 1
```

but still it can't execute the update query. Any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Hi @user2265229! How did you solve this issue. I am facing same challange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause of your problem is a trigger on `purchase_list`.  You should check if that is the case.

A secondary possibility is that the two queries are pointing to different databases with different table structures.

Answer (score 2):

Check datatype of `unit` column and try with

```
AND `unit`=1
```

If data type of `unit` is int else share table structure of `purchase_list.

Comment: How do answers like this get upvotes?  An error on the data type would not result in an unknown column error.  Changing the type of the constant has no bearing on the error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error occurs due to the use of same quotes (single ' or double ") for column name and value. For example, in my case: I used these two queries

Query #1:

```
UPDATE 'customerinvoice' 
SET 'invoice_status' = 2 
WHERE 'invoice_no' = '20200907202602_6'
```

Query #2:

```
'UPDATE customerinvoice 
 SET invoice_status = 2 
 WHERE invoice_no = 20200907202602_6'
```

and it throws this error.

> (1054, "Unknown column '20200907202602_6' in 'where clause'")

I solved this issue using:

Query #1

```
UPDATE 'customerinvoice' 
SET 'invoice_status' = 2 
WHERE 'invoice_no' = "20200907202602_6"
```

Query #2:

```
'UPDATE customerinvoice 
 SET invoice_status = 2 
 WHERE invoice_no = "20200907202602_6" '
```

Note: I am working in python and database is MySQL.